# How to apply autolayout to UISegmentedControl in tabelviewcell without coding in xcode?

Tags: xcode7.2

How to apply autolayout to UISegmentedControl in tabelviewcell (Storyboard) without coding in xcode?
Attached image below

[Attached image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IeALJ.png)

Comment: Are you looking for Universal App or only iPhone App ?

Comment: I am looking for only iPhone app but should align perfect on all iPhone devices